# Callback - Lottie Files

Tags: javascript, callback, lottie

I wan to play three different lottie files, one after each:

So I have three animations made with lottie files:

- Yellow Car
- Blue Car
- Red Car

What I want is to play first Yellow Car animation, when it finishes play Blue Car animation, then play Red car animation and once this finishes begin all again and again.

So this is the squence: Yellow Car -> Blue Car -> Red Car -> Yellow Car ...
(And repeat that sequence infinite)

Every animation lasts 3.2 seconds

But it only plays once, what is failing?

```
var animation1 = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('animation1'),
  path: 'https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_kqfglvmb.json',
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  name: "Blue Car",
})


var animation2 = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('animation2'),
  path: 'https://assets6.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_gdzapmjf.json',
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  name: "Red Car",
})

var animation3 = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('animation3'),
  path: 'https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/HN7OcWNnoqje6iXIiZdWzKxvLIbfeCGTmvXmEm1h/data.json',
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  name: "Yellow Car",
})


document.getElementById("animation1").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("animation2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("animation3").style.display = "none";
//const myTimeoutBlue = setTimeout(carBlue, 2000);

var yourCallback = function(second) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById("animation1").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("animation2").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("animation3").style.display = "none";
          animation1.play(); 
        second();
    }, 3200);
}

var yourSecondCallback = function() {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById("animation1").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("animation2").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("animation3").style.display = "none";
          animation2.play();
    }, 3200);
}

function function1(callback) {
          document.getElementById("animation1").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("animation2").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("animation3").style.display = "block";
          animation3.play(); 
    if (callback) {
        callback(yourSecondCallback);
    }

}

function1(yourCallback);
```

https://codepen.io/fernandocomet/pen/NWMjmqB

Comment: Why don't you combine all animation and use time markers for playing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [lottie-web](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web) and create eventlisteners instead of infinite callback functions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in generic way instead of using callbacks.

```js
var animation1 = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById('animation1'),
    path: 'https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_kqfglvmb.json',
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    name: "Blue Car",
});

var animation2 = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById('animation2'),
    path: 'https://assets6.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_gdzapmjf.json',
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    name: "Red Car",
});

var animation3 = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById('animation3'),
    path: 'https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/HN7OcWNnoqje6iXIiZdWzKxvLIbfeCGTmvXmEm1h/data.json',
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    name: "Yellow Car",
});

document.getElementById("animation1").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("animation2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("animation3").style.display = "none";

animation1.play();
animation2.play();
animation3.play();

var animations = ["animation1", "animation2", "animation3"];
var animationToPLay = animations[0];
var index = 1;

setInterval(() => {
    if (animationToPLay) {
        document.getElementById(animationToPLay).style.display = "none";
    }

    animationToPLay = animations[index];
    document.getElementById(animationToPLay).style.display = "block";
    index++;
    index = index === animations.length ? 0 : index;
}, 3200);
```

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#animation1, #animation2, #animation3{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.9.6/lottie.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="animation1"></div>
      <div id="animation2"></div>
      <div id="animation3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```